Problemas con fechas
Tengo un conjunto de fechas.

Pueden tener formato barra (01/01/2024)
Pueden tener formato guion (01-01-2024)
Pueden tener formato numérico (43101)
Con errores de doble barra (01//01/2024)
Con errores de número mal puesto (01/011/2024)

Pero lo habitual es que me llegue todo mezclado.
Quiero pasar todos los datos a formato fecha. Los que tengan el número mal puesto q salga como NA.
   datos <- read.table(text = '
    ID  F_uno   F_dos   Colores F_tres  datos F_cuatro
    1   43101   01/01/2024  P   01-01-2024  p    43101
    2   01/01/2024  01/01/2024  P   01/01/2024  p 43101
    3   43101   01/01/2024  P   01-01-2024  p  43101
    4   43101   01/01/2024  P   01-01-2024  p 43101
    5   43101   01/01//2024 P   01-01-2024  p 43101
    6   43101   01/01/2024  P   01-01-2024  p 43101
    7   43101   01/001/2024 P   01/01/2024  p 43101
    8   43101   01/01/2024  P   01-01-2024  p 43101
    ', header = TRUE)

Selecciono solo las columnas con fechas.
lista <- names(select(datos, starts_with("F_")))

Quito doble barra y guiones
for(i in lista) {
  datos[[i]] <-gsub('//', "/",datos[[i]])
  datos[[i]] <-gsub('-', "/",datos[[i]])
}

Y aquí el lio, habia pensado que si la fecha tiene una barra lo pase a un formato y si no la tiene, es entonces numérico, que lo pase a otro formato
for(i in lista) {
  if (any(grepl("/", datos[[i]]))) {
  datos[[i]] <- as.Date(datos[[i]], format = "%d/%m/%Y")
} else {
  datos[[i]] <- as.Date(as.numeric(datos[[i]]), origin = "1899-12-30")
}}

Pero no sirve para arreglar la 1ª columna (F_uno)
ID        F_uno      F_dos    Colores  F_tres   datos   F_cuatro
1  1       <NA>    2024-01-01    P    2024-01-01   p   2018-01-01
2  2 2024-01-01    2024-01-01    P    2024-01-01   p   2018-01-01
3  3       <NA>    2024-01-01    P    2024-01-01   p   2018-01-01
4  4       <NA>    2024-01-01    P    2024-01-01   p   2018-01-01
5  5       <NA>    2024-01-01    P    2024-01-01   p   2018-01-01
6  6       <NA>    2024-01-01    P    2024-01-01   p   2018-01-01
7  7       <NA>       <NA>       P    2024-01-01   p   2018-01-01
8  8       <NA>   2024-01-01     P    2024-01-01   p   2018-01-01


Esto lo podemos solucionar creando una función para que sea aplicada a todas las columnas que nos interesen, así, la función de corrección de fechas sería la siguiente:
corregir_fechas <- function(x){
  # creo un vector tipo fecha en el que guardaré las fechas corregidas
  fecha <- rep(as.Date("22/01/2019", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), length(x))
  
  # uniformando el separador para que sea solo '/'
  x <- gsub("/+|-+", "/", x)
  
  # Creo un vector de identificación de formato para diferenciar los casos numéricos de los no numéricos
  ind <- grepl("/", x)
  
  # Corrijo los que tienen "/"
  fecha[ind] <- as.Date(x[ind], format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  
  # Corrigjo los numéricos
  fecha[!ind] <- as.Date(as.numeric(x[!ind]), origin = "1899-12-30")
  
  # Retorno resultado
  return(fecha)
}

Ahora solo queda aplicarla a datos, para ello uso (por comodidad) el paquete dplyr:
  library(dplyr)
  datos %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with("F_"), ~corregir_fechas(.x)))
  ID      F_uno      F_dos Colores     F_tres datos   F_cuatro
1  1 2018-01-01 2024-01-01       P 2024-01-01     p 2018-01-01
2  2 2024-01-01 2024-01-01       P 2024-01-01     p 2018-01-01
3  3 2018-01-01 2024-01-01       P 2024-01-01     p 2018-01-01
4  4 2018-01-01 2024-01-01       P 2024-01-01     p 2018-01-01
5  5 2018-01-01 2024-01-01       P 2024-01-01     p 2018-01-01
6  6 2018-01-01 2024-01-01       P 2024-01-01     p 2018-01-01
7  7 2018-01-01       <NA>       P 2024-01-01     p 2018-01-01
8  8 2018-01-01 2024-01-01       P 2024-01-01     p 2018-01-01

El uso de dplyr es para no tener que escribir un loop (for) y que usando los 'verbos' apropiados me permita identificar las columnas (starts_with) e iterar (across) sobre ellas haciendo la corrección 'on-the-fly' (mutate).
